# separate to split on first number only, not second

Tags: r, string, text, stringr

I have a df with a bunch of rownames that represent variables in different zones. Currently, the variables and zones are together in the same text string, and inconsistently formatted.

I'm trying to use `stringr` to separate the zone codes (alphanumeric) into a different column and eventually pivot and stuff, but I'm having trouble getting my strings to split at only the First occurrence of a number, instead of at every occurrence.

```
df <- 
  tribble(
    ~variable,  ~value,
    "First Variable 4W",    20,
     "First Variable 4X5Y" , 22,
    "First Variable 5ZE" , 17,
    "First Variable 4X5Y" , 22,
    "First Variable 4Vs W" , 22,
    "Second Variable 4X",  50,
    "Second Variable4XW",  50,
    "Third Variable_4XW",  10,
    "Third Variable 5ZE",  10
  ) %>%
  as.data.frame()


# first tried with str_split_fixed, which separates correctly,
# but I don't know how to access both of the output columns.
# if you use glimpse(), you see that variable.1 and variable.2 are 
# actually one column that's a matrix, so I'm confused. 

df2 <- df %>%   
  mutate(variable = str_replace(variable,"_","")) %>%
  mutate(variable = 
           str_split_fixed(variable, 
                           pattern = "(?<=[a-zA-Z_])\\s*(?=[0-9])",
                           n=2))

# if I use separate, the splits get messed up on rows with merged zone values
# such as 4X5Y, and want to separate into 3 columns instead of two.
df3 <- df %>%
  mutate(variable = str_replace(variable,"_","")) %>%
  tidyr::separate(variable,
                  sep = "(?<=[a-zA-Z_])\\s*(?=[0-9])",
                  fill = "right",
                  into = c("variable", "zone"))
```

Desired output is a split column where the first is the variable name string, and the second is the code text, all lumped as is into one column.

```
> df2
#desired output:
        variable        zone  value
1  First Variable         4W    20
2  First Variable       4X5Y    22
3  First Variable        5ZE    17
4  First Variable       4X5Y    22
5  First Variable      4Vs W    22
6 Second Variable         4X    50
7 Second Variable        4XW    50
8  Third Variable        4XW    10
9  Third Variable        5ZE    10
```

(Note that this is what the output from `str_split_fixed` *looks* like, but if you try to manipulate it, you see that in that case it actually comes out as a df of 2 columns, such that the first column is a 2x9 matrix. I want it to come out as 3 columns such that I can use `df2$zone` or `df2 %>% select(zone)` to call the second column - in the current form, that is not possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please also include a few lines of your desired output? I'm not entirely sure how should the output look like

Comment: sure, I just added a bit. thanks!

Comment: Use the `extra = "merge"` argument in `separate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you've already solved the problem yourself. Here I just present a way to incorporate the `str_split_fixed()` result back to your `df`.

I'll first save the result of `str_split_fixed()` into a variable, then extract the corresponding columns from this matrix to incorporate back into `df`. This way, you can flexibly set the column names.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  tribble(
    ~variable,  ~value,
    "First Variable 4W",    20,
    "First Variable 4X5Y" , 22,
    "First Variable 5ZE" , 17,
    "First Variable 4X5Y" , 22,
    "First Variable 4Vs W" , 22,
    "Second Variable 4X",  50,
    "Second Variable4XW",  50,
    "Third Variable_4XW",  10,
    "Third Variable 5ZE",  10
  ) 

split_matrix <- str_split_fixed(df$variable, 
                pattern = "(?<=[a-zA-Z_])\\s*(?=[0-9])",
                n=2) %>% 
  gsub("_$", "", .)

df$variable <- split_matrix[, 1]
df$zone <- split_matrix[, 2]
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  variable        value zone 
  <chr>           <dbl> <chr>
1 First Variable     20 4W   
2 First Variable     22 4X5Y 
3 First Variable     17 5ZE  
4 First Variable     22 4X5Y 
5 First Variable     22 4Vs W
6 Second Variable    50 4X   
7 Second Variable    50 4XW  
8 Third Variable     10 4XW  
9 Third Variable     10 5ZE  

dim(df)
[1] 9 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `regexpr` to find the position of the first numeric:

```
position_of_first_numeric <- regexpr("[0-9]", df$variable)

varname <- substr(df$variable, 1, position_of_first_numeric-1)

len_of_string <- lapply(df$variable, nchar)

code_text <- substr(df$variable, position_of_first_numeric, len_of_string)
```

In `varname` I stored the part of the string before the first numeric, and in `code_text` the part after the first numeric, including the numeric.

**Edit**

To remove spaces, underscores and non-alphanumeric characters from `varname`:

```
varname <- gsub("\\W+$|_", "", varname)
```

**Edit 2**

Now it seems to me best to use `tidyr::unnest_wider()` after replacing `str_replace_fixed` by `str_replace` to get lists in the `varname` column:

```
newdf <- df %>%   
  mutate(variable = str_replace(variable,"_","")) %>%
  mutate(variable = 
           str_split(variable, 
                           pattern = "(?<=[a-zA-Z_])\\s*(?=[0-9])",
                           n=2)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(variable)
```

And then set names as desired.

Comment: According to the desire table, I think the author would also like to remove(ignore) the punctuation, which you can also consider in your answer.